# Unknown fragments & Failed to initiate one or more classes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I got those errors:
[image]
[image]
[image]

and this is my xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/overlayBAckground"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

        <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and in gradle dependecies I have this:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    def nav_version = "2.1.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

If you need more information please comment down below. i've looked on other posts but none of the solutions worked for me too. Maybe I've not looked deep enough but please help me if you know what is wrong.

Comment: did you tried invalidate caches and restart ?

Comment: I tried but it did not work the first time. However, after adding androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1' to my dependecies the error disappeared but I still got the Unknown Fragment